# Spring Boot Flash attribute not added to model after redirect

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I've been working quite a bit on this, searching the web for answer, but nothing conclusive. Here is my issue :

I'm trying to add **flash attributes** to a redirect for a registering form. At the moment, the verification works in the back-end. I've been able to parse the errors via `stdin`.

This is my code for both view and controller (example) :

```java
@PostMapping("/register")
public String processRegister(final RegisterForm registerForm, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("Error message test");
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("errors", list);
    return "redirect:/register";
}
```

```html
<div th:each="e : ${errors}">
    <div class="ui error message">
        <ul class="list">
           <li th:text="${e}"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The redirection works, from Chrome logs, I found the reponse `302` then, 200.

The only way I've been able to get something out of it so far, it by adding `@EnableWebMVC` in my **MvcConfig**, but the CSS and JS won't load.

I'd really love some hints here.

Thanks!

Comment: By adding `@EnableWebMvc` you disable the Spring Boot auto configuration, so you shouldn't be doing that. For flash attributes to work you need a http session, make sure that those work.

Comment: I have my session done with application.properties : `spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.session.jdbc.schema=classpath:org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-@@platform@@.sql` but still having the same issue

Comment: You don't need Spring Session for http session to be active. You just need a regular `HttpSession`. And if for some reason that has been disabled (or things aren't configured right) it won't work.